# Http Connection com timeout não funciona

Tags: android

Olá estou com uma classe para fazer a ler uma página HTML, mas queria que nela tivesse um tempo limite para a execução, meu código parece que faz isso, porém ele não funciona como deveria, ou seja, o tempo que coloquei não está acontecendo nada

```
private class GrabURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    InputStream is = null;
    int response = -1;
    URL url;
    URLConnection conn;
    String retorno = null;
    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(TelaLogin.this);


    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog.setMessage("Carregando. Aguarde...");
        Dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        Dialog.show();
    }
     protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {               
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            conn = url.openConnection();
            if(!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
            {
                retorno = "Erro-Tempo";
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConn.setReadTimeout(8000); // 8 segundos para ler
                httpConn.setConnectTimeout(4000); // 4 segundos para conectar
                httpConn.connect();
                response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                if(response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                {
                    is = httpConn.getInputStream();
                    retorno = inputStreamToString(is).toString();
                }
                else
                    retorno = "Erro-Tempo";
            }
        }catch(SocketTimeoutException ex){
            retorno = "Erro-Tempo";
            cancel(true);
        }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            retorno = "Invalido-Erro";
            cancel(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            retorno = "Invalido-Erro";
            cancel(true);
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        Dialog.dismiss();
        trataRetorno(retorno);     
    }

}
```

Comment: O que está acontecendo de errado, qual a sua pretensão com os timeout's? Qual o erro? Qual o problema?

Comment: Quero que se demorar muito para baixar o conteúdo seja cancelado a execução e gere uma mensagem para o usuário falando que a conexão dele está ruim.
Meu código fica tentando conectar o tempo todo, mesmo se demorar mais de 8 segundos, ele não cancela hora nenhuma.

Comment: Vixi, me parece ser um problema isso, veja esse [outro tópico em Inglês](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329277/why-timeout-value-is-not-respected-by-android-httpurlconnection), você está executando isso em uma `AsyncTask`?

Comment: Estou executando da forma que está ali em cima mesmo "new GrabURL().execute("...");"

Já tinha visto esse post, mas não consegui ter sucesso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá Gabriel Boa tarde,

Peguei seu código coloquei pra executar aqui e realmente não consegui fazer funcionar.
Comecei a procurar em alguns lugares e encontrei um código que usei em alguns projetos para fazer a requisição GET.

Verifique se esse código te ajuda:

```
private class GrabURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(TelaLogin.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Dialog.setMessage("Carregando. Aguarde...");
            Dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            Dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String retorno = null;

            try {               
                HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 4000);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 4000);
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

                HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(getRequest);

                HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                if (entity != null) {
                    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                    retorno = convertStreamToString(instream);

                    instream.close();
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException ex) {
                Log.e("TAG", ex.getMessage(), ex);
                cancel(true);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e("TAG", ex.getMessage(), ex);
                cancel(true);
            }

            return retorno;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String retorno) {
            super.onPostExecute(retorno);

            Dialog.dismiss();
            //trataRetorno(retorno);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();

            Dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Qualquer dúvida posta comentário!
Abs

Answer (score 0):

Também pode ser feito dessa forma:

```
//Recupera um content via HTTP GET.
public static InputStream getInputStreamFromUrl(String url) {
  InputStream content = null;
  try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
    content = response.getEntity().getContent();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.("[GET REQUEST]", "Network exception", e);
  }
    return content;
}
```

Referência:
http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-get-request-with-httpclient

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que o metodo de timeout da classe httpconetion nao possui nada implementado. Já tive este tipo de problema e o que eu fiz foi criar meu proprio timeout. Eu dava o start na linha antes de fazer a request, caso o retorno chegasse antes do timeout eu cancelava meu timer. Caso nao carregasse meu timer cancelava a requisicao. E ai o fluxo seguia como se fosse o timeout.